# Parallel processing with a function that uses parallel processing?

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-processing, multidplyr

I am using multidplyr package (my dataset, `map`, and `MyFnc`) for parallel processing in a `dplyr` syntax. However, `MyFnc` also uses parallel processing via `parallel` and `doSnow` libraries.

In this case, can I use parallel processing efficiently? Technically, what happens as a result of such a code?

Thank you,
Kind regards.

Comment: No, avoid nested parallelization. Usually it's best to only parallelize the outer loop, i.e., turn parallelization in `MyFnc` off.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please elaborate more on the reasons? Does it cause any calculation errors?

Comment: The issue is that each worker of the outer cluster has to create and manage another cluster. That kind of overhead is just inefficient. Also, how many CPUs do you have?

Comment: I have 8 CPUs, the first (outer) cluster uses six of them and the second cluster uses all of them.

Comment: Well, then you don't have enough CPUs to benefit from nested parallelization even theoretically.

Comment: Yes, that's true. So, now in practice, does it make parallelization in the first stage or in the second stage? Thanks.

Comment: Usually, you should parallelize the outer loop.

Comment: Roland could you elaborate why that is the case? If you have a huge dataset in the outer loop, say, and you're in a  windows enviroment, meaning no forking, why isn't it more effiecient to do parallel in the inner loop, where the copying of the data for earch worker is not that large? Do you get my question?